# What is a good way to mock database access in Python Impala

Tags: python, dataframe, mocking, python-unittest, impala

I am trying to mock the database access so that we don't connect to impala for unit-tests. I thought replacing the database tables returned with a Dataframe  object would do it, but tables have some more functionalities that dataframes don't support. Is there a way to create an object more similar to tables for testing?

Comment: You can return the tables as mocks.

Comment: How? can you give me an example on how to initialize a table without actually creating it?